# Classic ASP using Email and Local Server

Tags: email, iis-7, asp-classic, localhost

Basically, I have created a form with a To, From, Subject and Textbody, all named appropriately. What I need to know is what code I need to use Classic ASP to link to a local port, to test my code and send an email,

I have IIS installed at the moment and some other little programs, but I can't get my head around it.

Comment: i tried installing 'Free SMTP Server' and 'Local SMTP Server Pro' but to be honest i'm certain where _in the ASP Code_ to link them to a port, or if the IIS i have, can be used to link to a port. Thanks for the reply too!

Answer (score 3):

Sending an email in [vbscript](/questions/tagged/vbscript) is usually done in via CDO - example using gmails SMTP server (note the use of `configuration/smtpserverport` and `configuration/smtpusessl`)

```
Dim ObjSendMail
Set ObjSendMail = CreateObject("CDO.Message") 

ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = 1
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60

ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") ="info@thedomain.com" '#### Gmail Username (usually full email address)
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") ="password" '#### Gmail Password

ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Update

ObjSendMail.To = ""
ObjSendMail.Subject = ""
ObjSendMail.From = ""

ObjSendMail.TextBody = "Hello World"

ObjSendMail.Send
Set ObjSendMail = Nothing
```

Comment: @JackAllen no problem, dont forget to tick this as the answer :)

Comment: I need 15 Reputation to tick! I did try, as soon as i earn 15 ill come back haha